# More concise expression for "time it takes to perform an action"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a more concise expression for "time it takes to perform an action", where an action is anything that can be done by someone or something?

The expression would be used in a list of (unrelated) actions:

---

Actor: Person

Description: Walk in the park

Precondition: Good weather

________: 30 minutes

---

Actor: Program

Description: Load website

Precondition: Internet connection

________: 2 seconds

---

Actor: Animal

Description: Fetch!

Precondition: Woof! Woof!

________: 10 seconds

Comment: Consider: Time elapsed

Comment: Or, if in the future, *allotted* rather than *elapsed.*

Comment: Can't you just use the word 'Time'? I think that would work for filling in the blanks in your question.

Answer (score 6):

You may use ***[duration](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/duration)***:

> - the length of time something continues or exists. (The Free Dictionary)
> - the length of time that something exists or lasts. (M-W)

Examples:

> - *You should gradually increase the duration of your workout.*
> - *For the whole duration of the speech the bored audience fidgeted.*

Comment: Good answer.  "Duration" is what I was about to answer, but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

*Duration* is good, but I think it has a slightly different connotation than what you want, which is the amount of time required for a task to be completed, not exactly the amount of time something lasts. I would just use ***time*** in that context. I think the meaning would be clear.

Answer (score 0):

The *expected* time it will take to perform an action would be its **par**.

> Par \ˈpär\ noun :  an amount taken as an average or norm –[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/par)

```
Actor: Person
Description: Walk in the park
Precondition: Good weather
Par : 30 minutes
```

See, *Par Time* –[doom.wikia.com](http://doom.wikia.com/wiki/Par_time)